# Reverse query name clash on Django Abstract base classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am constructing Django model of files and I want to use an abstract base class for generic attributes and have it inherited by my specific models just like this.

```
class File(models.Model):
    options = (("published", "Published"), ("draft", "Draft"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="resource_file")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default="draft")
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="+",
    )
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    dateUpdated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class QuillFile(File):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return "posts/{filename}".format(filename=filename)


class UploadedFile(File):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, default="")
```

but I when I run makemigrations I got this error that says:

```
Reverse query name for 'classrooms.UploadedFile.folder' clashes with reverse query name for 'classrooms.QuillFile.folder'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'classrooms.UploadedFile.folder' or 'classrooms.QuillFile.folder'.
```

I tried changing and doing what's on the hint and put the assignee field on the children model and have them different related_name but I still got an error. Help.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name) on how to resolve this. This is caused by `QuillFile` and `UploadedFile` sharing the same related_name for `folder`

Comment: Try this: `related_name='%(class)s_resource_file'`.

Comment: @BrianDestura yeah thank you I didn't see that. Silly me!